# How to make sign Out after login using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a simple authentication app in Android using Firebase authentication. Till now I am successful in signing the user in, however the issue is that the user remains signed in, and I can't find a way to sign him out.

Here is my MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //tracking the sign in and singn out operations
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user!=null){
                System.out.println("User logged in");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("User not logged in");
            }
        }
    };
}


public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }
}


public void buttonClicked(View view){

    EditText editemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    EditText editpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    String email = editemail.getText().toString();
    String password = editpass.getText().toString();


    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 //   Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Success.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Success.class));
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                       // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

If you want to perform some action after sign out then use this one.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```